# Преобразование командой sed конфигурационного файла

Tags: linux, sed

Есть следующая задача. Есть конфигурационный файл с некоторыми параметрами, пример

```
        option interface 'wi_fi'
        option leasetime '12h'

config host
        option name 'cabinet4'
        option dns '1'
        option mac '90:E6:BA:F7:E9:31'
        option ip '192.168.111.104'

config dhcp 'fi_fi'
        option interface 'fi_fi'
        option leasetime '12h'

config host
        option name 'qwe'
        option dns '1'
        option mac '00:15:58:72:58:A1'
        option ip '192.168.1.254'
```

Надо преобразовать его к виду

```
20:E6:BA:F7:E9:31 192.168.111.104
20:15:58:72:58:A1 192.168.1.254
```

Иными словами нужно выбрать все секции **config host**, взять из них **MAC** и **IP** и записать их в другой файл построчно. При этом секции **config host** могут находится не друг за другом и в них может быть разное количество параметров!
Как я понял это можно сделать утилитой **sed**, но чего то не могу сообразить КАК?
То что смог сделать это выбрать из файла начало секции + 5 строк за ней
`sed -n '/config host/,+5w ethers' dhcp`. Но проблема в том, что строк в секции может быть как больше так и меньше, поэтому так не подходит. К тому же непонятно как искать в самой секции параметры? Искать просто по **option mac** или **option ip** не получиться, так как они встречаются не только в **config host**.
Единственная идея искать после начала секции когда появится новая строка в которой нет табулятора, но как это сделать неясно.

Подскажите можно ли такое сделать с помощью **sed** или надо писать скрипт, где построчно разбирать файл?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
awk '/config host/,$0==""' FILE |awk -F"('| +)" '$3=="mac" {mac[x]=$5;x++} $3=="ip"{ip[y]=$5;y++} END{for(i in mac) print mac[i],ip[i]}'
```

первый `awk` оставляет только секции `config host`

*(условие: секция должна быть неразрывна и отделятся пустой строкой или концом файла)*

у второго `awk` устанавливаем разделителями как пробелы так и кавычку', далее там же проверяем третий столбец на наличие условия (`mac` или `ip`) при соблюдении которого формируем массивы отдельно для `mac` и `ip` записывая в них пятый столбец(то что между кавычек), ну и под конец в секции `END` выводим сформированные массивы в удобном для нас виде.

**п.с.**

на случай когда помимо пробелов присутствует еще и табуляция

```
awk '/config host/,$0==""' FILE |awk -F"('|[[:blank:]]+)" '$3=="mac" {mac[x]=$5;x++} $3=="ip"{ip[y]=$5;y++} END{for(i in mac) print mac[i],ip[i]}'
```

Comment: Возможно я что то не так сделал, но эта связка ничего не выводит. Вместо FILE, как я понял нужно вписать имя файла источника?

Comment: да, `FILE` это исходный файл, а первую часть выводит `awk '/config host/,$0==""' FILE` ?

Comment: Да все выводит.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Поправил и все заработало, проблема была в номерах.           awk '/config host/,$0==""' dhcp | awk -F"('| +)" '$2=="mac" {mac[x]=$4;x++} $2=="ip"{ip[y]=$4;y++} END{for(i in mac) print mac[i],ip[i]}'

Comment: @Иван Жуков, хм, возможно проблема из за копирования вашего примера выше, так как там одни пробелы, а в исходном файле там может быть табуляция, поэтому нумерация и сместилась.

Comment: @Иван Жуков, добавил в ответ вариант с присутствием еще и табуляции как разделителя

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой `sed`:

```
$ sed -rn "N; s/\\n//g; s/.*mac '(.*)'.*ip '(.*)'.*/\1 \2/p" file
90:E6:BA:F7:E9:31 192.168.111.104
00:15:58:72:58:A1 192.168.1.254
```